# PHP Webdriver wait for a dynamic drop down list to populate

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I am writing a php script to test out a webpage with 2 drop down lists, the first dropdown gets populated as soon as the page is loaded

After list1 is populated, i have to select a value then the second list gets populated as well
see attached image

[image]

With the PHP webdriver, i can easily select an option from the first dropdown list like so

```
$select = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('make')));
$select->selectByIndex(2);
```

After i select an option from list1, i have to wait for the page to populate the second list i.e the Mode & Body list,
for this is use below code

```
$driver->wait()->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::visibilityOf($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('model')))
);

//model & body
$select = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('model')));
$select->selectByIndex(2);
```

However, the webdriver doesn't seem to wait until the second list is populated, and therefore it throws an error saying the element is stale

[image]

How can i wait until the second list is populated before trying to access it ?
I am using PHP Chrome webdriver on a windows machine

Comment: _"i have to wait for the page to populate the second list"_ - does the second select get created or made visible at this point only? Or was it "there" before already, but only had a placeholder option? You are checking for when it becomes visible - which in the latter case, would of course not be sufficient.

Comment: @CBroe after the page is loaded, the second select is disabled and it has a placeholder.
Only after select 1 is selected is the second select populated and enabled.

Comment: Then `visibilityOf` is the wrong condition to use, because it is visible already. You need to find a condition that triggers when it is not disabled any more.

Comment: this happens because the options are still populating.  Easiest solution is to add a long enough sleep after selecting the first option.  Otherwise you catch the Stale Element exception and re-get the element(s).  (the Select object will get all options, but it can't know when those options are fully populated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the `refreshed` condition; to get the code working.
Here is a walkthrough of why this worked

The said method waits until an elements get repainted and refreshed

Here is a complete implementation

```
$driver->wait()->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::refreshed(WebDriverExpectedCondition::stalenessOf($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('model'))))
);
```